# Add InArgument of Activity to Root Activity

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have workflow designer which I use for authoring workflow; now when I drop any activity to Designer I catch that in ModelChanged event and can get the all the InArguemnt of that type now I want to add those Argument to the WorkFlow as well; it is like in Visual Studio I can define Arguments through I want to add that automatically while authoring work flow.

How can I do this ?

Thanks
Ocean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Walk up the model tree (ModelItem.Parent.Parent.Parent...., add the new arguments:

activityBuilderModelItem.Properties["Properties"].Collection.Add(new DynamicActivityProperty {
    Name = "argumentName", Type = typeof(InArgument)
    });

etc.